# Is there a benefit to painting concrete floors?

Tags: concrete, flooring, paint

In every place I have ever lived, I've seen cement floors painted (unfinished basement and garage). In every case over time I've observed the paint flaking, peeling and creating a terrible mess. I would love nothing more than to remove all floor paint from my current property.

What I would like to know is if there's a practical reason this is done? Does the paint do anything beneficial for the protection of the concrete surface or is this simply a cosmetic finish that could be removed without consequence?

Comment: Easier to keep clean. May help reduce water infiltration. May be more attractive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a cosmetic finish that can be removed without consequence. Makes a lot more sense to pretty up concrete with something other than paint if longevity is a concern. Acid stain, sheet vinyl, engineered hardwood, tile, stone…